# To extract Top feature names from list numpy

Tags: list, numpy, feature-selection

Here I have a compilation of feature names in feature_names, each name been taken from column if X_train, Y_train of a dataset.

`neigh` is an MultinomialNB classifier which has been fitted with X_train and Y_train of a dataset.

I can't figure out now How to extract top features from feature_names by using neigh MultinomialNB classifier.

So I wrote code below using numpy

```
max_ind_positv=np.argsort((neigh.feature_log_prob_)[1])[::-1][0:10]
top_pos=np.take(feature_names,max_ind_positv)
```

But it shows the following errors:

1) `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'take'`

2) `IndexError: index 3997 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7`

Please someone show me correction on how to get top 20 feature names.

Comment: You seem to have clobbered `np` with a list at some point (that's what error 1 is saying). Restart your session and be sure to do `import number as np`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use `np.take()`, you can just index into an array of strings. So to get the features in order of *decreasing* importance, you can do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> features = np.array(['feat1', 'feat2', 'feat3'])
>>> coeffs = np.array([0.2, 0.02, 2.0])
>>> features[np.argsort(coeffs)[::-1]]
array(['feat3', 'feat1', 'feat2'], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: How to generate coeffs ? Can you please show me a code snippet similar to code I posted, So that I can directly run it on my machine ?

Comment: It depends on the classifier, but for `MultinomialNB` I guess it would be `neigh.feature_log_prob_[class]` where `class` is each class in turn (say). But generically it's just an array of numbers you want to sort the `features` list by.

Comment: So, my code should look like this --> feature = np.array(feature_names), coeffs = np.array(neigh.feature_log_prob_[1]), features[np.argsort(coeffs)[::-1]]  ?

Comment: Can I somehow share my code with you over-gmail so you can help do necessary changes, I feel frustrated as I'm stuck here for over more than a week and need to complete this ML course, please help.

Comment: actually now it shows new error--> IndexError: index 3998 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7, I can't interpret anything out of it.